# Only match numbers, commas and dots and ignore whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a pricelist that I would like to 'normalize', using the Javascript flavor of Regex.

Sample input:

```
1
1,99
1.99
10
100
5999 dollars
2 USD
$2,99
Our price 2.99
Price: $ 20
200 $
20,-
6 999 USD
```

Desired output:

```
1
1,99
1.99
10
100
5999
2
2,99
2.99
20
200
20
6999
```

I am getting rather good results with `/([0-9.,\s]+)/` but I've got two problems:

- The last sample line returns `6` instead of `6 999`. I am not sure if it's possible to "remove" the space, preferably I would like to get `6999` but `6 999` is close enough.
- Second last line returns `20,` (which is logical since I include commas) but rather want `20` only in these cases.

Comment: I am not a regex expert. But, you can add a `or` for `,` followed by any digit. Also why `\s`, if you do not want to include whitespace ?

Comment: is `5 999` coming out correctly but `6 999 USD` not?

Comment: Also worth noting, the \s will match a newline (at least on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tD5wR1)), so you'll get a match like of `1.99<newline>6 999` even without the m flag (maybe a regex101 bug?).

Comment: What JavaScript function are you calling with the input string and the regular expression?

Comment: @Jashwant Re-phrased first problem, see above.

Comment: FYI added <pre> to the online demo so you can clearly see the output like you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that is straight out of [Match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204)

The regex: `(?:\d|[.,](?=\d))+|(\w+|.)`

The left side of the alternation matches characters we want: digits, or dots and commas followed by digits. The right side matches and captures word characters or a single character, and we know these are not characters we want because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

When Group 1 is set, we replace with an empty string.

See the output in the [online demo](http://js.do/code/38450)

```
<script>
var subject = "1 \n\
1,99 \n\
1.99 \n\
10 \n\
100 \n\
5 999 \n\
2 USD \n\
$2,99 \n\
Our price 2.99 \n\
Price: $ 20 \n\
200 $ \n\
20,- \n\
6 999 USD";

var regex = /(?:\d|[.,](?=\d))+|(\w+|.)/g;
replaced = subject.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (group1 == "" ) return m;
    else return "";
});
document.write("<pre>");
document.write(replaced);
document.write("</pre>");
</script>
```

**The Output**

```
1
1,99
1.99
10
100
5999
2
2,99
2.99
20
200
20
6999
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8h8Tk/

If you really wanted to normalize your input, I would suggest you choose either , or . for your decimal value separator. However, if not, the jsfiddle above gives the correct output.

```
var output = input.replace(/[^0-9\.,\n]|,[^0-9]/g, "");
```

All it does is remove the characters you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing it in two steps, first convert all commas to dots:

```
x = x.replace(/,/g, '.')
```

Then get rid of everything else:

```
x = x.replace(/[^.|0-9]+/g,'')
```

Comment: Doesn't look as though they want to replace commas with periods, both appear to be valid in the sample data above.

Comment: Then it's even simpler: `x = x.replace(/[^.|,|0-9]+/g,'')`

Comment: I would do this: `input.replace(/[^0-9\.,\n]|,[^0-9]/g, "")`. It removes everything that is not a number, dot, comma, or newline and it removes commas if not followed by a number.

Answer (score 0):

Replace what you don't want:

```
result = subject.replace(/[^\d.,]+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `/((?:[\d.,\s]+)?[\d]+)\b/g` It extends from your original version